# How to structure code when introducing new If statement before chunk of logic

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring, structure

So lets say I have a function like so:

```
function doStuff () {
    let myVar = 3;
    doSomething()
    ......doManyThings()
}
```

And now I want to introduce some logic like so:

```
function doStuff () {
    if( true ) {
        doThis()
        ....do All The Stuff Above
        doThat()
    } else {

        ....do All The Stuff Above
        doAnotherThing()
    }
}
```

What is a good solution to handle the refactoring of this function without introducing a completely new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doStuff () {
    let myNewFunction = function () {
          ....do All The Stuff Above
    }
    if( true ) {
        doThis()
        myNewFunction()
        doThat()
    } else {
        myNewFunction()
        someOtherNewFunction()
    }
}
```

Should be fine. 
Consider moving the common functions into an object. Check out [this article](http://crushlovely.com/journal/7-patterns-to-refactor-javascript-applications-value-objects/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the condition only for `doThis()`

```
function doStuff () {
    if ( true ) {
        doThis()
    } 
    ....do All The Stuff Above
}
```

EDIT

If you use the same part again, use the [don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle and move the parts into a new function, maybe inside of the actual function for the right scope.

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad example on my part. I have edited my question to reflect this.